# How do I do this in JQuery? (get the HTML returned from AJAX-GET and turn it into an object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

```
$.ajax({
                method:"get",
                url:"/wall",
                data:"ajax=1",
                beforeSend:function(){},
                success:function(html){
                   $("#grid_mason").append(html);  //Add the next boxes to the Grid.
                   $(this).masonry({ appendedContent: $( html ), animate:false, resizeable:false });

                    });

                }
            });
```

http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/appending.html

I'm using that Masonry plugin, and it kind of talks about appending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the masonry applied to `#grid_mason` then try changing the code from

```
$("#grid_mason").append(html);
$(thiz).masonry({ appendedContent: $( html ), animate:false, resizeable:false });
```

To this

```
$("#grid_mason").append(html)
    .masonry({ appendedContent: $( html ), animate:false, resizeable:false });
```

Not sure I can suggest anything else without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you need to refactor your code as:

```
var thiz = this;
$.ajax({
    method:"get",
    url:"/wall",
    data:"ajax=1",
    beforeSend:function(){},
    success:function(html){
       $("#grid_mason").append(html);  //Add the next boxes to the Grid.
       $(thiz).masonry({ 
            appendedContent: $( html ),
            animate:false, 
            resizeable:false});
    });
   }
});
```